Why useState does not work in this scenario
I am studying Front end development and got stuck on this seemingly very simple problem, but I can't figure out why it does not work.
When I click on "Add to cart" button I want to conditionally display quantity input instead of the button (Also will try to do that by id, but that's for another topic).
Product Card Image for reference
I wrote this code for ProductCard component:
import productList from "../data/productList";
import { useState } from "react";

function ProductCard() {
  let quantityValue = 0;

  let [newProductList, changeProductList] = useState(productList);

  function revealQuantityInput(id: number) {
    changeProductList({
      ...newProductList,
      quantityVisibility: true,
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Form submitted correctly!");
  }

  return (
    <>
      {productList.map((item) => (
        <div className="p-6 mb-6 [&>*]:mb-4" key={item.id}>
          <img src={item.image} />
          <div
            className="bg-green-600 p-2"
            onClick={() => revealQuantityInput(item.id)}
          >
            {item.quantityVisibility ? (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  id={"quantity" + item.id}
                  min="1"
                  max="9"
                  step="1"
                  onChange={(e) => (quantityValue = Number(e.target.value))}
                  className="bg-gray-300 w-[150px] opacity-100 mr-3"
                />
                <button className="bg-gray-300" type="submit">
                  Add to Cart
                </button>
              </form>
            ) : (
              <p>Add to Cart</p>
            )}
          </div>
          <p>{item.category}</p>
          <p>{item.name}</p>
          <p>{item.price}</p>
          <p>{JSON.stringify(item.quantityVisibility)}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default ProductCard;

This is my data file:
import productTypes from "../types/productTypes"

const productList:productTypes[] = [
    {
        id: 0,
        image: "../../public/images/image-waffle-mobile.jpg",
        name: "Waffle with Berries",
        category: "Waffle",
        price: 6.50,
        quantityVisibility: false,
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        image: "../../public/images/image-creme-brulee-mobile.jpg",
        name: "Vanilla Bean Crème Brûlée",
        category: "Crème Brûlée",
        price: 7.00,
        quantityVisibility: false,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image: "../../public/images/image-macaron-mobile.jpg",
        name: "Macaron Mix of Five",
        category: "Macaron",
        price: 8.00,
        quantityVisibility: false,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        image: "../../public/images/image-tiramisu-mobile.jpg",
        name: "Classic Tiramisu",
        category: "Tiramisu",
        price: 5.50,
        quantityVisibility: false,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        image: "../../public/images/image-baklava-mobile.jpg",
        name: "Pistachio Baklava",
        category: "Baklava",
        price: 4.00,
        quantityVisibility: false,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        image: "../../public/images/image-meringue-mobile.jpg",
        name: "Pistachio Baklava",
        category: "Baklava",
        price: 4.00,
        quantityVisibility: false,
    },

]

export default productList

And this is types file:
interface productTypes {
    id: number;
    image: string;
    name: string;
    category: string;
    price: number;
    quantityVisibility: boolean;
}

export default productTypes

When I try to update the state in the function
revealQuantityInput

I get this error:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'quantityVisibility' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<productTypes[]>'.

How come this can be undefined?
I try to update the data list with new TRUE value while also preserving old values like id, name etc., but it does not work.

it looks like your list is an array when you are passing a new object.

You have a productList array but when you update it you update it to be an object, and the compiler is rightfully complaining about the mismatch. Change {} to [].

I spotted something, the first one is there
function revealQuantityInput(id: number) {
    changeProductList({
      ...newProductList,
      quantityVisibility: true,
    });
  }

Your state is an array of product and when you change the list it became an object is it intended?
Then in your render, you use the productList and not the newProductList (which is initialized to productList here)
You will probably need to do this
function revealQuantityInput(id: number) {
        changeProductList((prev) => prev.map((product) => {
            if (product.id === id) {
                return { ...product, quantityVisibility: true, };
            }
            return product;
        });
    }

